# How to make globally shared objects available to freemarker templates in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

What is the best way of making global shared objects available to freemarker templates when using Spring Boot 2.x, without losing Spring Boot's FreeMarker auto configuration?

The underlying mechanism for doing this is Spring Boot's [`FreeMakerConfigurer.setFreemarkerVariables`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.html#setFreemarkerVariables-java.util.Map-), which in turn calls FreeMarker's [`Configuration.setAllSharedVariables`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setAllSharedVariables-freemarker.template.TemplateHashModelEx-)

However, there is no obvious way (to me) to modify the FreeMarkerConfigurer that is setup by [`FreeMarkerServletWebConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker) beyond the predefined freemarker properties that Spring Boot supports. (Search for "freemarker" [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)).

A common approach is to create a custom `FreemarkerConfigurer` bean, but I believe that then loses some of the auto configuration provided by spring boot, especially around the handling of various external properties.

One option that seems to work is to use a BeanPostProcessor like this:

```java
public class CustomFreeMarkerConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    Object sharedWithAllFreeMarkerTemplatesObj = new Object();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
    throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof FreeMarkerConfigurer) {
            FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = (FreeMarkerConfigurer) bean;

            Map<String, Object> sharedVariables = new HashMap<>();
            sharedVariables.put("obj", sharedWithAllFreeMarkerTemplatesObj);
            configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(sharedVariables);
        }

        return bean;
    }
}
```

It seems like there should be a cleaner way of doing it, perhaps by somehow extending or configuring `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory`, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution from spring git](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8965#issuecomment-369845407)

Spring Boot 2.0 breaks the solution provided by @wo8335224, as FreeMarkerWebConfiguration is replaced by FreeMarkerServletWebConfiguration, which is unfortunately package-private and thus cannot be subclassed.

A currently working solution is to configure freemarker.template.Configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfig {
    public FreemarkerConfig(freemarker.template.Configuration configuration) throws TemplateModelException {
        configuration.setSharedVariable("name", "whatever type of value");
    }
}
```

Internally FreeMarkerConfigurer#setFreemarkerVariables delegates its work to freemarker.template.Configuration#setAllSharedVariables.

Comment: You will lose some of the FreeMarker auto configuration if you use this approach. I mentioned that in my question, and in that same git issue, I actually reference this question/answer.  Perhaps you do not need the auto configuration, in which case this would be acceptable.

Comment: The following settings are loaded normally under SpringBoot2.3:
spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute, spring.freemarker.template-loader-path, spring.freemarker.content-type